# Show javascript popup error message in angularjs form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to show javascript popup error message when processing form inputs.But i cant figure it correctly.Here is my html file

```
<form name="form" ng-app ng-submit="register(user)">
 <div class="controls">
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email" required />
        <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.required">Required</span>
        <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" required />
        <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.name.$error.required">Required</span>
        <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.name.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my controller i want to populate javascript popup error message.Here is my controller

```
angular.module('starter.controllers',[])

    .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {


        $scope.register=function(user){
          //this will work 
           alert(user.email)
          //this wont work
           if(user.email=="")
            alert("Email required");
        }

    })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `type="email"` the model will not be populated unless the input field actually contains a valid email, so `user.email` will be `undefined` and not `""`.

Comment: So i need to  perform validation only in controller.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need valid form inputs to execute `ng-submit`, unti you call `register` programatically. This means that `user.email` won't ever be equal to `""`.

Second, look at the standard HTML5 validation. It will show "Email is invalid" on form submit.

Third, advanced validation can be done through custom directives that have access to [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) and element. This allows to use [HTML5 validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation), or add custom error handling (like `alert`) via `$watch` or `$parsers` and `$formatters`. AngularJS provides concern separation mechanism, consider using it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i used form validation methods in angular docs.